# Gradle with SpringBoot plugin build fail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I currently have a project which have hierarchy like this:

```
shared |
       |-consumer
       |-provider
```

**build.gradle** of project **shared** looks like this:

```
apply plugin:'org.springframework.boot' //if i remove this line,everything works fine
apply plugin:'io.spring.dependency-management' 
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName='A.M'

sourceSets{
    main{
        java{
            srcDir './src'
        }
    }
}

subprojects{
    apply plugin:'java'
    apply plugin:'application'
    sourceSets{
        main{
            java{
                srcDir './src'
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies{
        implementation project(':shared')
    }
    mainClassName = 'B.M'
}
```

And my **shared:provider** project's **build.gradle** is empty

main class of **shared:provider** is:

```java
package B;

import A.*;

public class M {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

When i execute `gradlew build` , it reports `can't resolve symbol A`

```
C:\Users\ratsafalig\Desktop\Java\HelloDubbo\demo>gradlew build

> Task :shared:provider:compileJava FAILED
C:\Users\ratsafalig\Desktop\Java\HelloDubbo\demo\provider\src\B\M.java:3: 错误: 程序包A不存在
import A.*;
^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:provider:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date
```

---

My question is,when i remove `apply plugin:'org.springframework.boot'` in `shared` project's build script, everything works fine.

Is this because `org.springframework.boot` plugin override the `build` task or what?

Comment: The Spring Boot Gradle plugin should only be applied to Spring Boot **application** projects. It should not be applied to library projects since it re-configures bundling tasks such as JAR, to produce a Spring Boot fat JAR.

Comment: @Francisco Mateo  So that means gradle plugin may override tasks such as `build`,`run`,right?